# Is it possible to get the amount of emails sent and received in workspace by Google API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I need to get the amount of emails sent and received in a Google Workspace.

Basically, I want to know if it is possible to get the data of this report by some Google API.
I get this print directly from Google Admin.

[image: Report of Emails in Google Admin]

I tried using Gmail API.

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const oAuth2Client = require('./oauth.js')
const gmail = google.gmail({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: oAuth2Client
});

await gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me' }) // success
await gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'othermail@domain.com' }) // permission error
```

But I can only get the emails from the authenticated account. And I need from all accounts in domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all messages in every account, you will need to use [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials) to impersonate the account.

However, it's easier and more performant to find the closest property in the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/gmail) that fits what you need, like `num_emails_exchanged`.